# Trying to display image in an HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I've tried all code variations that are online. I just want to display an image on a canvas. I've tried code from this site.

```
window.onLoad=function(){
  function draw(){  
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");  
    var img = new Image();  
    img.src = 'images/ball.png';  
    img.onload = function(){  
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);  
    };
  };
};
```

It's not the file path that's a problem, that has been tested without the images folder. There are no errors in the console. Thanks.

Comment: Kind of solved. It was window.onLoad. I deleted that from the js, and moved the script tag from the head of the HTML file to the bottom of the body tag, and the image displayed. I'm not sure why it worked but had an inkling it may work because it needs to load the canvas before the script?

Comment: Window.onLoad event does not mean that all page elements are loaded yet. That is why it worked with script being at the end of body.

Comment: onload does mean that all elements are loaded : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload

Comment: O ok. I think it's because i did onLoad then. If i simply changed it to onload it would work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One search in google and there you go with complete jsfiddle example:

```
// Grab the Canvas and Drawing Context
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Create an image element
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/gwlPu.jpg";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jimrhoskins/Sv87G/

Comment: Thanks yes it's all over the internet, i tried them all. The problem was actually my script tag being in the head of the html file.